# Why are colors different between RAW and JPEG when both are viewed in Lightroom?

Tags: raw, color, jpeg

Yesterday I was shooting images of trees that were wrapped in the beautiful baby lights that stores put in holidays. I noticed, when I went back home and checked my photos, that there is a slight difference in colors of the baby lights in RAW and JPG images.

I don't understand why there should be any difference. I thought that they should look the same. The colors in the RAW file of baby lights are more vivid and stronger than the colors in JPG.

I'm using a Canon Rebel T3i and the color space is AdobeRBG. I'm using Adobe Photoshop Lightroom.

Comment: Can you post cropped images of the two and we can see the difference? Was the setting exactly the same?

Comment: What software are you using to view the JPEGs? Sounds like it could be trying to display the JPEG using default sRGB colorspace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do my photos look different in Photoshop/Lightroom vs Canon EOS utility/in camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/why-do-my-photos-look-different-in-photoshop-lightroom-vs-canon-eos-utility-in-c)

Comment: With the edit, another possible duplicate which may seem more directly related. Take a look at [How do I fix RAW images that appear washed out in Lightroom 3?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6575/how-do-i-fix-raw-images-that-appear-washed-out-in-lightroom3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This likely has to do with the way the RAW is being (pre) processed and rendered in the RAW viewer. The RAW file is not simply a raster image with pre-defined color values for each pixel, so there is a wide range of ways that the file can be interpreted depending on a variety of factors, including the RAW engine powering the viewing software itself.

Comment: Also, as Imre pointed out, with the camera set to AdobeRGB (which doesn't necessarily apply to the RAW file, depending on how it is viewed) might make the JPEG file colors appear less saturated.