# What Linux software might deliver a better default rendering of a Nokia 1020 dng file than an old version of darktable?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, linux, darktable, raw-vs-jpeg

I wanted to migrate from windows(lightroom) to Linux (Darktable) for several reasons, I've got a Nikon D3100 as my main camera, I haven't had problems with .NEF files, but today I tried to edit one of my Nokia's picture but once I open the picture it looks like this:

[image]

So contrasted, it looks really different than the .jpg image

Do you know any alternative software to edit this kind of files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you probably really want is identifying the setting used to create the JPG and take them as starting point in your RAW editor. It's probably a duplicate, let me find it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does raw to jpg conversion differ in different editors?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70766/why-does-raw-to-jpg-conversion-differ-in-different-editors)

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17694/why-are-colors-different-between-raw-and-jpeg-when-both-are-viewed-in-lightroom

Comment: Hint: reset the base curve module ("curva base") in darktable, and then adjust it for the contrast you *want*. But that's not what you asked...

Comment: Could be worth trying a newer version of Darktable. I notice v2.2.2 mentions support for the Nokia 1020. http://www.darktable.org/2017/01/darktable-2-2-2-released/

Comment: @vclaw: Nice catch, I didn't even notice that little detail of the screenshot. I tried a couple of the images from [here](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/18984_Nokia_Lumia_1020_RAW_camera_ca.php) in 2.2.3 out of curiosity, and found the default darktable rendering to compare favorably to the OOC images. But ultimately the answer is still to adjust to taste. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as @vclaw pointed out, one alternative would be the *current* version of darktable... another would be [RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/). I grabbed one of the RAW/jpeg sets presented [here](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/18984_Nokia_Lumia_1020_RAW_camera_ca.php) and exported the default rendering of those two programs.

First, the rather over-saturated OOC image:[image]

The RawTherapee 5.0.r1 version:[image]

...and the darktable 2.2.3 version:[image]

Note that darktable gave a warning that it had no bundled color matrix for the camera, and was using one embedded in the file.

So much for default rendering. Both pieces of software are intended to be used to *alter* the default rendering to what the user wants, and are very capable in this regard, once you learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your dissatisfaction could be solved by changing the base curve, since this camera probably doesn't have a sensible default in Darktable. Since there probably isn't a good default base curve for this file, go to the base curve module and in the presents select something like "Nikon Like" or "EOS Like". There are only a few so one might be closer to what you think the scene should look like by default.

Comment: ...but update your copy of darktable first! :P