# Pictures I took from my Nikon D5000 have low contrast. Whats wrong with my camera?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, camera-controls, nikon-d5000, contrast

The pictures I have taken with my **Nikon D5000** have low contrast, is there anything wrong with my camera? Every time I import pictures to Lightroom I have to adjust contrast to get a clear picture.

Pictures appear as if they have a thin gray overlay.

Is there any settings I need to apply to the camera to get a decent level of contrast for all pictures I take.

Comment: What lens?  And can you post some examples, before with the low contrast and then what you expect it to look like?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [How do I fix RAW images that appear washed out in Lightroom3?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6575/). ParagM, does that address your question?

Comment: Same with all lenses? Is sensor clean? Presumably you have a degree of in-camera customisation. Do you have scene modes - are you using a non standard colour space? If you import pictures from another camera how do they look? Post a few photos hat have NOT been modified.  Just post the links here since you can't directly upload an image.

Comment: When in doubt do a camera reset, its in the setup menu. You may have selected one of the dull color modes like neutral or an effect or simply lowered contrast. Without an example we can only guess.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear - the OP has had two years to provide some examples of the problem, and without that we can't really help.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can qualify low contrast and attach a before and after photo. But generally you need more light for more contrast. If outdoors, consider shooting only before sunset where the direct light is stronger than the diffused ambient light. Enable the histogram and see how broad the distribution is.

added: Low contrast is characterized by narrow histograms in the middle. Shoot a target with Black and white and grey. It should show up on the camera and your editor as spikes at both ends and middle. and play your your light reading settings. Point/multipoint etc.